# setTimeout does not start the function

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

I have a function that use `setInterval()` method to watch css propertie change('cause in some browser we don't have event to do that), now I need to write an unit test for this function.

```
var counter = 0;
function callback() {
    counter++;
}
$('body').append('<div id="testDom" style="color:red"/>');
dom = $('#testDom').get(0);
watcherId = DomWatcher.watch(dom, 'color', $.proxy(callback,this));
function testWatch() {
    $(dom).css('color', 'green');
    setTimeout(assertEqual(counter, 1), 1000);
}
```

Then the assertion fail.
I'm sure the watch function works well, it check css properties change every 100ms. Just don't come up with a good way to write the unit test..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling `assertEqual` immediately and passing it's return value to `setTimeout`. You need to pass a function to `setTimeout`.

```
function assert() {
    assertEqual(counter, 1);
}
setTimeout(assert, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do

```
setTimeout("assertEqual(counter, 1)", 1000);
```

or

```
setTimeout(function(){assertEqual(counter, 1);}, 1000);
```

Comment: Your second option is much, much better.

Comment: Yes, better to know both but use second.

Comment: A problem is that if I choose the first option. It would say assertEqual cannot be found, 'cause I didn't attach it to global scope.

Comment: I've never found a case where I needed the first option or thought it was a better way to do it.  I've never thought it made sense to type a string when I could type an actual function reference that will already be precompiled into p-code when the script loads rather than parsed when the timer runs.